# SharePoint 2013 Workflow not linked to Contenttype anymore

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, content-type, reusable

I've recently come across a strange problem in SharePoint Designer 2013 where I create a SharePoint 2013 Workflow, associate it with a custom contenttype and start editing the workflow.

If I save and publish the workflow (not associating it to a list yet), restart SharePoint Designer, I see my Workflow not linked to my custom Contenttype anymore.

Any ideas why?

[image: SP reusable workflow contenttype association]

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of the `SharePoint 2013 workflow platform` doesn't support associated workflow with a content type.

If you tried to create a new Reusable workflow using SharePoint Designer, you will note that the **Content Type** drop down list is grayed out as shown below.

[image]

---

**The only available workaround is to use** `SharePoint 2010 workflow platform`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

M.Qassas has already highlighted the limitation in his answer. But there is a workaround to it.

1. Click on the file tab in SharePoint Designer
2. Select Reusable Workflow (towards the bottom) from the given options
3. On the right side of the page, you'll have the option to associate the content type to your workflow enabled.

Refer below screenshot for reference.

[image: Reusable Workflow]

Comment: Hi @Amit, that's indeed the way I set it up initially. 
But as I stated above: after I've set the contenttype, at some point during development of the workflow, it loses the association. In the overview page I see "Contenttype: All" and every field I previously used in the workflow is blanked out (e.g. replaced by the generic blue 'field' reference).

Comment: Hi @Nilsvb, Are you trying to move the workflow from one environment to another?

Comment: Hi @Amit: no, just creating a simple SP 2013 workflow.